# supertest mock-fs crash other tests

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, supertest

Some requests to my nodejs back-end are Ajax-request, for these routes i use a token authentification, "the token is saved on the fs".

I use jest-supertest for testing.

If i test directly the function which save the token (mocking the fs) it works.

the function:

```
async function saveToken(token) {
    try{
    
        const err = await promisify(fs.writeFile)(
            '/opt/app/tmp/token.txt',
            token,
            {encoding: 'utf8', flag: 'w'}
        )

        if(err) throw Error('error in close: ', err)
        else return true
```

the test: // works

```
const mock = require('mock-fs');
const { saveToken } = require('../token')
const { readFile } = require('fs').promises

it('makes sure the token is saved', async() => {
    const token = 'theIsTheToken'
    mock({
        '/opt/app/tmp/token.txt': ''
    });

    await saveToken(token)
    const dts = await readFile('/opt/app/tmp/token.txt', 'utf8')

    mock.restore(); 
    expect(dts).toEqual(token)  
})
```

But i don t want to run a unit test, i want check the full request. The problem is if i mock the test of the route the other test of the file crash. Look like it mocks the fs in all the tests ...?

the route logic

```
exports.getAddReview = async(req, res, next) => {
    const token = Math.random().toString(36).split('.')[1].slice(0, 10)
    try {
        const hash = await encrypt(token)
        const tokenSaved = await saveToken(token)
        if(!tokenSaved) throw Error(REVIEW_CT,' - token is not save')

        res.render('tprmain/edit-review', {
            pageTitle: 'edit-review',
            path: '/edit-review',
            editing: false,
            token: hash
        })
    } catch(e) {
        next(new ProcessError('A system error occured, please try again'))
    }   
}
```

the test:

```
it('save token', async() => {
    
    const resp = await global.signin()

    // mock({
    //  '/opt/app/tmp/token.txt': ''
    // });


    await resp
        .get('/add-review')
        .send()
        .expect(200)
    
    // mock.restore();  
})
```

if i run the test like above i get this err, which is normal the fs is not mock.

```
error from save token:  [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/opt/app/tmp/token.txt'] {
```

so i uncomment to mock the fs of this request but then all other test(on the same test file) crash

```
// mock({
        //  '/opt/app/tmp/token.txt': ''
        // });
```

the err are

```
 FAIL  controllers/__test__/carsCt.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/jerome/Documents/code/tprSiang/api/controllers/__test__/carsCt.test.js'

      at runTestInternal (node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:202:27)

 FAIL  controllers/__test__/picsmainCt.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 

'/home/jerome/Documents/code/tprSiang/api/controllers/__test__/picsmainCt.test.js'
    
          at runTestInternal (node_modules/jest-runner/build/runTest.js:202:27)
etc...............
```

Thanks if someone have a solution, because i would like to test the full route instead of just the function.

================== See here the full test settings ==========

the jest setup file

```
const { MongoMemoryServer } = require('mongodb-memory-server')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const session = require('supertest-session')

const keys = require('../config/keys')
const app = require('../index')

let mongo 
beforeAll(async() => {
    // process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test'

    mongo = new MongoMemoryServer()
    const mongoUri = await mongo.getUri()

    await mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    })
})

beforeEach(async() => {
    const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections()

    for(let c of collections){
        await c.deleteMany({})
    }
})

afterAll(async() => {
    await mongo.stop()
    await mongoose.connection.close()
})

// afterEach(async() => {   
//  mock.restore(); 
// })

global.signin = async() => {
    let testSession = session(app)

    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        testSession.post('/postsignin')
            .set('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
            .send({
                name: keys.adminName1,
                password: keys.adminPasswordClear
            })
            .end(err => {
                if(err) reject(err)
                resolve(testSession)
            })
    })
}
```

the tested file where i can not mock the fs

```
const app = require('../../index')
const session = require('supertest-session')
const keys = require('../../config/keys')
const Review = require('mongoose').model('Review')

const mock = require('mock-fs');

//  test get reviews
it('makes sure getReviews need authentification', async() => {
    await session(app)
        .get('/reviews')
        .send()
        .expect('Location', '/admin/getsignin')

})

it('get all the reviews', async() => {
    const resp = await global.signin()
    
    await resp
        .get('/reviews')
        .send()
        .expect(200)
})

// test postAddReviews, all token logic is tested separatly
it('add some correct reviews', async() => {
    
    const dataSample = new Review({
        name:'addReview',
        comment:'comment addReview',
        picUrl:'http://urlPicture.com',
        quand: Date.now()
    })
    const savedDts = await dataSample.save()

    const reviewsDB = await Review.find()

    expect(dataSample.name).toEqual(reviewsDB[0].name)
    expect(dataSample.comment).toEqual(reviewsDB[0].comment)    
    expect(dataSample.picUrl).toEqual(reviewsDB[0].picUrl)  
})

// test the mock, the mock restore is in afterEach() in the setup.js file
// it('test getAddReview', async() => {
//  const resp = await global.signin()
//  mock({
//      '/opt/app/tmp/token.txt': ''
//  });
// 
//  await resp
//      .get('/add-review')
//      .send()
//      .expect(200)
// })
    
// does not work as can test the token in query
// it('add some incorrect picUrl field', async() => {
//  const resp = await global.signin()
//  
//  const dataSample = {
//      name:'addReview',
//      comment:'comment addReview',
//      nopicUrlfield:'http://urlPicture.com',
//      quand: Date.now()
//  }
// 
//  const response = await resp
//      .post('/add-review')
//      .set('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
//      .send(JSON.stringify(dataSample))
//      .expect(417)
// })

// test postEditReview
it('makes sure postEditReviews need authentification', async() => {
    await session(app)
        .get('/edit-review/:id')
        .send()
        .expect('Location', '/admin/getsignin')

})

it('update a review', async() => {
    const resp = await global.signin()

    // save/set original review
    const dataSample = new Review({
        name:'addReview',
        comment:'comment addReview',
        picUrl:'http://urlPicture.com',
        quand: Date.now()
    })
    const reviewSaved = await dataSample.save()

    // create updated review
    const updatedDatas = {
        name:'addReview updated',
        comment:'comment addReview updated',
        picUrl:'http://updated.com',
        quand: Date.now()
    }
    // save updated datas
    await resp
        .post(`/edit-review/${reviewSaved._id}`)
        .set('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        // .send(JSON.stringify(updatedDatas))
        .send(updatedDatas)
        .expect(302)

    // get the reviews
    const reviewsDB = await Review.find()   

    expect(updatedDatas.name).toEqual(reviewsDB[0].name)
    expect(updatedDatas.comment).toEqual(reviewsDB[0].comment)
})

// test getDeleteReview
it('makes sure the getDeleteReview route need auth', async() => {
    await session(app)
        .get('/delete-review/67546')
        .send()
        .expect('Location', '/admin/getsignin')
})

it('delete a review', async() => {
    const resp = await global.signin()

    // save/set original review
    const dataSample = new Review({
        name:'addReview',
        comment:'comment addReview',
        picUrl:'http://urlPicture.com',
        quand: Date.now()
    })
    const reviewSaved = await dataSample.save()

    // delete the review
    await resp
        .get(`/delete-review/${reviewSaved._id}`)
        .send()

    // get the reviews
    const reviewsDB = await Review.find()   
    
    expect(reviewsDB.length).toEqual(0)
})
```

Comment: It looks like the mock filesystem is getting left behind and jest is hitting it when trying to load more tests. You should probably move `mock.restore()` (which must always be run to put back the real FS) to an `afterEach` block to ensure that it is run even when tests fail.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It doesn t help, but the err changed `ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/home/jerome/Documents/code/tprSiang/api/node_modules/terminal-link'`. Nothing run anymore, just this err is printed out

Comment: Strange. You should definitely use `afterEach` though - it's mentioned in the mock-fs documentation. You might want to update your question with a full test suite file that produces this error (preferably a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), since it's hard to see how it could be happening from the snippets you have shown.

Comment: I just tested it using afterEach as you said. Ok i will update the question, but then it gonna be a "long" question